# Error when installing Liferay 7 CE with Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, liferay

I try to install Liferay 7 ce ga3 on centos and I get the following error. I installed oracle jdk 8 in centos and extracted the bundle in /opt. 
Since I want to connect with oracle 12c I completed the steps in this article: https://www.dontesta.it/en/2016/04/13/liferay-7-ce-how-to-add-support-for-oracle-db/ and I uploaded ojdbc6.jar and liferay-portal-oracledb-support-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in $LIFERAY_HOME/$TOMCAT_HOME/lib/ext

```
Loading file:/opt/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/portal-ext.properties 13:25:50,890 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:75] Determine dialect for Oracle 12.1 13:25:51,046 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:148] Found dialect org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect 09-Mar-2017 13:25:51.494 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener  java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/dao/db/BaseDB
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:585)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1794)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/dao/db/BaseDB
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.ArrayApplicationContext.<init>(ArrayApplicationContext.java:31)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:243)
        ... 13 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/liferay/portal/dao/db/BaseDB
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at it.dontesta.labs.liferay.portal.dao.db.OracleDBFactory.doCreate(OracleDBFactory.java:14)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.db.BaseDBFactory.create(BaseDBFactory.java:39)
        at com.liferay.portal.dao.db.DBManagerImpl.getDB(DBManagerImpl.java:117)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.db.DBManagerUtil.setDB(DBManagerUtil.java:64)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.hibernate.PortalHibernateConfiguration.newConfiguration(PortalHibernateConfiguration.java:140)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:505)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.hibernate.PortalHibernateConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(PortalHibernateConfiguration.java:68)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
        ... 26 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.dao.db.BaseDB
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 47 more

09-Mar-2017 13:25:51.499 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file 09-Mar-2017 13:25:51.501 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors 13:25:51,533 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][PortalContextLoaderListener:114] java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.DirectServletRegistryUtil.clearServlets(DirectServletRegistryUtil.java:27)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:132)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4859)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:585)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1794)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 13:25:51,540 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][PortalContextLoaderListener:114] java.lang.NullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.reset(HotDeployUtil.java:53)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4859)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:585)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1794)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 13:25:51,562 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][PortalContextLoaderListener:114] java.lang.IllegalStateException: The system has not be activated yet. java.lang.IllegalStateException: The system has not be activated yet.
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.setStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1442)
        at com.liferay.portal.bootstrap.ModuleFrameworkImpl.stopRuntime(ModuleFrameworkImpl.java:518)
        at com.liferay.portal.module.framework.ModuleFrameworkUtilAdapter.stopRuntime(ModuleFrameworkUtilAdapter.java:121)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:146)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4859)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:585)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1794)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 13:25:51,564 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][PortalBeanLocatorUtil:109] BeanLocator is null 09-Mar-2017 13:25:51.565 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener  com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorException: BeanLocator is not set
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate(PortalBeanLocatorUtil.java:74)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.closeDataSource(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:377)
        at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4859)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:585)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1794)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

09-Mar-2017 13:25:51.588 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor /opt/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml has finished in 17,910 ms 09-Mar-2017 13:25:51.596 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] 09-Mar-2017 13:25:51.609 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] 09-Mar-2017 13:25:51.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 17981 ms
```

Any ideas what causes the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, the correct path where to deploy del jar is specified at https://github.com/amusarra/liferay-portal-oracledb-support

Answer (score 2):

It is solved. I placed liferay-portal-oracledb-support-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in wrong folder. It should be in $LIFERAY_HOME/$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib.
Thus the installation started.

Comment: This is a great news.

Answer (score 1):

The code you're linking was built for Liferay 7 CE GA1, and it might need to be adopted to GA3 (read: You shouldn't install GA1). Liferay 7 gets more and more modularized, and it might be that some classes moved from the core to a module, thus breaking classpath dependencies (hopefully while maintaining API compatibility). As the technique to add Oracle-compatibility to Liferay seems quite brute-force (it goes to the global classpath instead of being a module) I can easily imagine this.

Note that I have no access to Oracle, so I can't try out that module. Take my explanations with a grain of salt.

Comment: I am working on docker containers and in a few attempts I managed to connect to the database. So I don't think that it is related to version compatibility of the module.

Comment: Hi @olaf-kock, To extend support to other databases, Liferay has decided to refactory code to use Java SPI (Service Provider Interface). SPI is the mechanism that allows you to extend / change the behavior within a system without changing the source. It includes interfaces, classes or methods that the user extends or implements in order to obtain a certain functionality. Also on GA3 java SPI remained and continues to run

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @AntonioMusarra, my answer is just a wild guess based on the nature of the stacktrace in the question. As I wrote in my answer: I have no OracleDB available, so I couldn't test at all. The solution shows that it's an issue of the code location instead of the actual code. Thanks for providing this code by the way.

Answer (score 0):

To connect **Liferay 7.2 with Oracle 12C** I used to do:

1. **ojdbc8.jar** - get this from Oracle installation home and into

**liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2\tomcat-9.0.17\lib\ext**

2. **liferay-portal-database-all-in-one-support-1.2.1.jar** - Download latest jar from Maven Repository (E.g. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/it.dontesta.labs.liferay.portal.db/liferay-portal-database-all-in-one-support/1.2.1)  and put into

**\liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2\tomcat-9.0.17\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib**

It works perfectly.